# Combinations with replacement

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In a factory there are 40 employees. A union of 5 people is being chosen. How many combinations are there for a union, if the union contains of 5 different roles, and each employee can hold more than one role (up to 5).

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that each role can be assigned to one person, though any one person may have more than one role.

There are $\binom{40}{5}$ ways to choose five members of the union.  Since there are five roles to assign, and each role can be assigned to one of $5$ union members, there are $5^5$ ways that the five roles can be assigned to the five chosen union members.

Using the product rule, that gives us $$\binom{40}{5} \cdot 5^5 = \frac{40!}{5!\,35!\,}\cdot 5^5 = \frac{40\cdot 39 \cdot 38\cdot 37 \cdot 36}{24}\cdot 5^4$$ totals ways this task can be accomplished. You can ease the computation by doing some nice cancellations.

Comment: I don't see why someone would downvote this answer, the question was unclear.

Comment: @Bananarama The answer is correct. No misunderstanding on my part. It's likely a down-vote from someone with an agenda.

Comment: I don't doubt the answer is correct, but by the comment on my answer from the op I think what the meant is that the committee doesn't necesserily have to be of five persons, moreover for each task there is exactly one person with that task.

Comment: "A union of **five people** must be chosen." How much clearer can that be? I agree that for each role, there is exactly one person assigned that role.

Comment: I agree with amWhy, the question is unclear (I just copied it from the source). You could interpret it either way I guess, and so both answers are correct, depends what the author meant. Surely no reason for a "down-vote"

Comment: @amWhy: I hope you have a nice time my missed friend. I am back just to have a short visit of my poor profile. I am very glad you have been in top users as you were already. I am doing research and don't have enough time to help others as it should be. Thanks for being my close friend here. Miss you so much Amy. :-)

Comment: @B.S. HELLO! I miss you so much! Thanks for coming by and letting us know you're doing well. How can I contact you to keep in touch?

Comment: Thanks, @B.S. I've got it now! ;-)

Comment: Yes, indeed, @Sami It was nice to have B.S. visiting us!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the tasks are president, banker,librarian, minister, and general.

Then there are $40$ options for president, $40$ options for banker, $40$ options for librarian,$40$ options for minister and $40$ options for General. Thus there are $40^5$ possible committees.

Comment: There can't be multiple persons with the same task. It's the other way round, there can be tasks with the same person. Theoretically, it can be that the union is built from one person only, if he is assigned to all 5 roles. At least that's how I understood the question, maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now. I will edit.

Comment: Since it is possible for $1$ person to have all five rolls, you still need to account for how many ways, in such a scenario, four additional committee members can be selected. Or, say one person has three roles, and another two roles. Three remaining union positions still need to be filled. Or 2, 2, 1 (leaves two more people to serve as union members. Etc. Hence the need to choose five of 40, then assign them roles.

Comment: @user162354 The question clearly states "A union of **five people** is being *chosen*." We must first choose 5 of 40 people. Then, Who takes on what roles must be decided and there are $5^5$ ways this can happen.